# Convert init to systemd

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, init, systemd

I'm running a customized linux distribution built with reference to ubuntu 12.04 which has init as user space startup process by default. But now I want to switch over to systemd init system which is available from ubuntu 15.04. I installed the systemd components & libraries and also written unit files to replace init.d service daemon scripts.

I want to know how the system can start the systemd as init process?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel starts the init system located in `/sbin/init` (see also this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process#Kernel_startup_stage))
This process is responsible for starting every other process and should not die or exit (this will result in a panic).

One can also temporarily change the init daemon by using the init boot param on the kernel command line: `init=/path/to/init_program`.

Depending on your bootloader you should be able to edit the kernel commandline and test your changes.